# addon firefox - open window with specific dimensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have made an addon for firefox. I install it but i have two problems.I use windows.open because the panel isn`t suitable for me because if the user want to copy something in it, the panel is disappearing when he leaves it. So i have windows. I have this code:

```
var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var windows = require("sdk/windows").browserWindows;
var self = require("sdk/self");
var widget = widgets.Widget({
id: "open window",
label: "test",
contentURL: self.data.url("favicon.ico"),
onClick: function() {
windows.open({
url: "http://www.example.com",
onOpen: function(window) {
}
});
}
});
```

I don`t know where to put the attributes of width,height,no scroll  :/ in order to be displayd as a popup window.

And the second problem is that the button is displayed at the bar of addons.How it is possible to display it at the nav bar next to firebug?

Answer (score 0):

The `windows` module does not support specifying window features.

You could use the unstable [`window/utils`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/window/utils.html#openDialog%28options%29) module and the `openDialog` function to provides.
Or you could get yourself [`chrome`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html) privileges and re-implement the stuff yourself. The [implementation](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/window/utils.js#L247) of `openDialog` is surprisingly pretty straight forward and can be borrowed from easily.

Either way, you'll need to wait for a window to actually fully load (`newWindow.addEventListener("load", ...)`) before you can safely interact with it. Or get somewhat hackish and listen for the first `open` event via the [`windows`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/windows.html#open) module.

Comment: i prefer the way of the openDialog but it doesn`t work this one.          var widgets = require("sdk/widget");
var { openDialog } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var window = openDialog('http://www.example.com', {
  name: 'jetpack window',
  features: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    popup: true
  }
});
    
});
 
var widget = widgets.Widget({
  id: "open-window",
  label: "open-window",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  onClick: function() {
   window.openDialog({
   
});
  }
});    can you help me with this?